# Missing App Menu in Summer 17 Classic

Tags: sandbox, menu, summer-17

Following the upgrade of our sandboxes to Summer 17 at the weekend, 3 of our 9 active sandboxes are missing the App Menu, even for Sys Admins.  They're all Classic orgs and I've checked App assignments for that profile and they should all be there, but the whole App menu is missing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a known issue, I have the same problem:

[image]

Salesforce has posted about it here:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EAI4QAO&title=summer-17-app-menu-picker-missing-post-upgrade-ise-being-observed-when-creating-a-custom-app

Comment: FYI, this is has now been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that a refresh has solved it for the sandboxes I can refresh now.